# How to solve the limit $\lim_{(x, y, z) \to (0, \sqrt{\pi},1)}{e^{xz}\cos{y^2}-x}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I started to solve this limit:

$$
\lim_{(x, y, z) \to (0, \sqrt{\pi},1)}{e^{xz}\cos{y^2}-x}
$$

But I'm confused on how keep going, I thought in convert the limit with spherical coordinates:

$x = p\sin{\beta}\cos{\theta}$

$y = p\sin{\beta}\sin{\theta}$

$z = p\cos{\beta}$

Then,

$$
\lim_{p \to 0}{e^{(p\sin{\beta}\cos{\theta})(p\cos{\beta})}\cos{(p\sin{\beta}\sin{\theta})^2}-p\sin{\beta}\cos{\theta}}
$$

I'm not sure whether this is the correct way to solving this one

Comment: The function is continuous at the given point, so you can just plug it all in.

Comment: Also, if you did use spherical coordinates for some reason, then $\rho\to0$ isn't the correct limiting point - it's some point with $\rho=\sqrt{\pi+1}$....

Answer (score 0):

As  Adriano comment the function is continuous  now just you let $x=0$ and $y=\sqrt{\pi}$ and $z=1$ so we have $$\lim\limits_{(x,y,z)\to(0,\sqrt{\pi},1)}e^{xz}\cos y^2-x=e^{0}\cos \pi-0=-1$$